# Keycloak authentication for a Spring Boot SOAP webservice based on custom atribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, keycloak

We're using Keycloak to protect a Spring Boot SOAP application. We want to handle authorization to the application based on information from the user's attributes in keycloak, as opposed to the standard 'roles based' access.

For example, we can use the standard keycloak spring boot adapter with the following configuration:

```
keycloak.security-constraints[0].authRoles[0]=special-role
keycloak.security-constraints[0].securityCollections[0].patterns[0]=/service/*
```

This will ensure that only users with 'special-role' can access the service. But is it possible to write a custom filter to look at the value of the user's attributes instead of her roles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution we came to is to use the Spring Security adapter for Keycloak, and then specify our own bean for inspecting the token:

```
@Component
public class WebSecurity {
    public boolean check(Authentication authentication) throws Exception {
        boolean result = false;
        ...
        return result;
    }
}

// In the web security configuration
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SOME_URL)
                .access("@webSecurity.check(authentication)")
```